# Laravel Controller beforeFilter not working as expected

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

My controllers constructor looks like

```
function __construct(MessageRepository $message)
{
    $this->beforeFilter('canViewThisMessage', array('only', 'show'));
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->pagesize = 8;
    $this->pageTitle = 'messages';
}
```

and I expect the filter to be applied on show action. Which looks like

```
public function show($id)
{
    $message = Message::findOrFail($id);

    return View::make('messages.show', compact('message'));
}
```

But the filter is applied on all actions, not just on show method! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of:

```
$this->beforeFilter('canViewThisMessage', array('only', 'show'));
```

you should use:

```
$this->beforeFilter('canViewThisMessage', array('only' =>  ['show']));
```

or

```
$this->beforeFilter('canViewThisMessage', array('only' =>  'show'));
```

looking at [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#controller-filters)

Comment: @brainless Relax Nobody knows everything and sometimes you can miss easy solutions